# Eclipse plugin-activation on texteditor opening

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I was wondering if it is possible to activate a plugin when any texteditor is opened/created? I would like to add a general functionality which should be usable in every texteditor, though I can't find an extensionpoint which allows me to add listeners to newly opened texteditors (unless I use the org.eclipse.ui.startup extension point, which is not recommended)

thanks in advance

Comment: Use an `IPartListener` to be told about all part (editor, view) events. What makes you think the startup extension point is not recommended?

Comment: I know how to register listeners etc. I'm just searching for a good extensionPoint which activates the plug-in (so init/setup methods etc. can be called for registering listeners etc.). If there are no alternatives of the startup extension points, I will defenitly use it, but just in case...

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is no such extension point.

Comment: Too bad, that means I got to listen for newly created textEditors as well. Anyways, thanks for the fast reply